# Enabling/Disabling a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone programming and when I use this code to enable/disable a button nothing happens. I connected my button through an IBOutlet and I know when I disable it in viewDidLoad it works. I just cant figure out why this method isn't working.

```
- (void) multiplicationButtonPressed {
    if (multiplicationIsPressed) {
        multiplicationButton.enabled = NO; 
    } else {
        multiplicationButton.enabled = YES; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `multiplicationIsPressed`? Perhaps it's always false.

Comment: Do you set the variable multiplicationIsPressed? Have you connected the IBOuttlet of the button in IB to the button?

Comment: once you disable the button the IBAction will no loner work because you have disabled the button to do so. Try using seleced state for your purpose. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check that your IBOutlet had connected properly for this button or not and then

use this piece of code

```
- (IBAction) multiplicationButtonPressed 
 {
    multiplicationButton.selected = !multiplicationButton.selected;
 }
```

That's it. You don't need to have any boolean flag. It works like toggle.

Comment: multiplicationButtonPressed method will not be called if you disable the button. I dont think it will work.

Comment: @Chandan shetty SP sorry my mistake. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys that was exactly the problem. It makes so much more sense now. Seriously thanks a billion.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check that your IBOutlet had connected properly for this button or not and then

Use this code

```
 - (IBAction) multiplicationButtonPressed 
 {
     if (multiplicationIsPressed) {
          multiplicationButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
     } else {
          multiplicationButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of reasons this could be failing. Without more context, we can only guess.

- If `multiplicationButtonPressed` is called before the view is loaded, the button hasn't been created yet.
- You say `multiplicationButton` is hooked up as an IBOutlet in IB, but you could be wrong. Is it actually connected?
- If `multiplicationButtonPressed` is the action for a button or other control, it's probably not actually hooked up to whatever it is supposed to be hooked up to. This is particularly likely since you declared it as `(void)` rather than `(IBAction)`, so unless the declaration in the .h file doesn't match IB won't even see it.
- If (as the name implies) `multiplicationButtonPressed` is the action for `multiplicationButton` itself, it will never be called when the button is not currently enabled because a button with `enabled` set to NO will never respond to touches.
- Or the same problem could exist somewhere higher up the view hierarchy: no subview of a view with `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO can respond to touches either.
- Or it is possible that your layout is screwed up, and whatever button is supposed to be triggering this event is not actually within the bounds of all of its parent views. If said parent view doesn't clip to bounds, you could still see the button but not interact with it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for leaving out more information. I have multiplicationButtonPressed set up as a BOOL value. I have to IBActions, if i press the multiplication button it disables the button and sets it to YES. If I press the = button it sets it to YES, enabling it again. However, when I press the = button it never enables it again. The disabling part works fine however.